# Can I log errors into datadog via datadog tracer?

Tags: go, logging, datadog

I have a lots of golang application using zerolog, which are writing logs errors/info etc. into a file on the local server.

I work in a international cooperation, which has decided to use Datadog for logging. The cooperate decision is to use tracer and NOT dogstatsd.

I have been supplied with the following example code:

```go
    import (
    ...
    "gopkg.in/DataDog/dd-trace-go.v1/ddtrace/tracer"
    )
    
    func main(){
        ...
        tracer.Start(
            tracer.WithService("CVR-service"), // Specify the service name
            tracer.WithEnv("Stage"),           // Specify the env
            tracer.WithServiceVersion("2.0"),
        )
        defer tracer.Stop() 
         
        mux := httptrace.NewServeMux()
        
        mux.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
            w.Write([]byte("CVR-Service-Started!"))
        })
        http.ListenAndServe(":8080", mux)
    }
```

As i read the [datadog documentation](https://docs.datadoghq.com/tracing/glossary/) tracer is used for measuring performance or requests, and the examples are primarily on http
requests and I have not found examples of logging errors. Many of my application doesn't use http either. I have made endless googling and haven't found anything usable. The central cooperate support can't give a solution to my problem.

Is there any kind of way to inject zerolog into tracer or reverse? e.g:

```go
    f := some_kind_of_iowriter_from_tracer()
    logger := zerolog.New(f).With().Timestamp().Logger()
    r, err := Myfunc()
    if err != nil {
        logger.Panic().Err(err).Msg("HELP")
    }
```

If not how do i use tracer to log errors (and info) ?

Or is it mission impossible to use datadog tracer for this purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tracing is part of APM which is for instrumenting code to measure the performance of specific methods and dependencies and getting insight into how code runs. Ingesting logs is part of Log Management. You need to use the Datadog agent or create some kind of forward to tail your log files and send them via the [HTTP API](https://docs.datadoghq.com/api/latest/logs/#send-logs).